# [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: fb is not defined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I followed everything as shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wuShuZYtJ0w&list=PLB4AdipoHpxYPjGo0n2m6tmCLud_iSEbv&index=46) and I keep getting an error: [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: fb is not defined".

```html
uploadImage(e){
  let file = e.target.files[0];
  var storageRef = fb.storage().ref('products/'+ file.name);
  storageRef.put(file);
  console.log(e.target.files[0]);  
},
```

[error photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVNVe.jpg)

Comment: Did you `import {fb, db} from '../firebase'` ?

Comment: Show us the full code. where did you get this `fb` variable? maybe it's `db` not `fb`.

Comment: I resolved it, thanks to all who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

The naked, unqualified `fb` variable is in global scope, and evidently not defined there.  If `fb` is a vue component property, it should be referenced as `this.fb`.  If it's not a vue property it is probably really `undefined`.